# Angular $resource and errorResult JSON handling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, rest, ngresource

I have a Spring Rest service exposed and from Angular controller, using Angular Resource service I communicate with it. In my service I have implemented exception handling and with standard error response I return an Json object that contains data like errorCode, erorrMessage and errorDescription.

Now i want to handle that Json in errorResult just like in the successResult in order to show the errorDescrption on the web page. How can I do this?

This is the example of the resource service usage:

```
   var configGet = config.get({}, function(successResult) {
        $log.debug("Service responded successfully");
        $log.debug(successResult);
        $scope.data = successResult.content;
        $scope.totalItems = successResult.totalElements; 
    }, function(errorResult) {
        $log.error("Service responded with ERROR");
        //How to get errorDescrption  from erorrResult?
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got the solution and its very simple, I dont know how I didnt see it...

To get errorDescrption is simple as this:

```
var errorDescrption  = errorResult.data.errorDescrption
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your question that you are returning Json in case of error also with proper errorCode and errorMessage , so you can handle easily in success block like this.

Here Ajax request will return in suucess block even if there is any exception handling in your service because at service side you are returning proper json in case of error also

```
var configGet = config.get({}, function(successResult) {
            if (successResult.errorMessage == "something" && successResult.errorCode=="codeNumber") {

                $log.error("Error Occured");

            } else {
                $log.debug("Service responded successfully");
                $log.debug(successResult);
                $scope.data = successResult.content;
                $scope.totalItems = successResult.totalElements;
            }
        }, function(errorResult) {
            $log.error("Service responded with ERROR");
            //How to get errorDescrption  from erorrResult?
        });
```

Comment: I could do that, but what actually happens is that the service returns the errorResult, not the successResult. For example, I can get the errorResult.status but I dont know to to get my Json object which is also return in the response...